# iMessage: Merely having the Google/Analytics Pod dependency causes a _NSXPCDistantObject exception

Tags: ios, google-analytics, imessage

I have an iOS 9+ project that uses both Google Analytics and Firebase for Analytics.

This project also has an iMessage Extension.  The extension is targeted for iOS 10.0

If I keep the GA Pods in my pod file like this:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
```

Then I get the popular, dreaded exception on Startup of the first controller (subclass of MSMessagesAppViewController) :

```
**[_NSXPCDistantObject _remoteViewDidBecomeReadyForDisplay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**
```

This error occurs in system internals, and there is no stack trace that leads back to any of my code.

Also:  I've commented out all GA code, including Logging, Configuration and Initialization.  I only have the GA Pods being linked to the Target, and not even used.  The exception still persists.

Now, If i comment out the GA Pods, everything works fine, and the first controller loads up.

My GA versions being pulled by CocoaPods:

```
Using GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
Using GoogleIDFASupport (3.14.0)
```

So I'm faced with a choice:  To spend more time looking for a GA version that would work with an iMessage extension, or to Migrate the part of my system that uses GA to use Firebase Analytics instead.

You can reproduce this issue with a brand new, blank iMessage target that launches a Hello World main screen, and adding the GA Pod to it.

Is GA trying to hook into something in the UI that doesn't exist?

Any suggestions on a solution?

Comment: Does the problem still persist if you replace `Google/Analytics` with `GoogleAnalytics` in your Podfile?

Comment: You are right...  I double checked and the difference between Google/Analytics and GoogleAnalytics is the first one brings in some extra stuff:  "Google", "GoogleInterchangeUtilities", "GoogleNetworkingUtilities", "GoogleSymbolUtilities", "GoogleUtilities".    When I switched to the one you suggested, it removed those 5 dependencies, and now the extension starts up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the pod itself; `Google` is deprecated. Change

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

to

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

Comment: You are right, doing this makes the error go away.  I would have to refactor my code because all the APIs appear to be different in the new version.  We just moved to using Firebase, which is their recommended solution going forward.